# Why is the gap between consecutive twin primes always a number of integers divisible by 3?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For example: (5,6,7)8,9,10(11,12,13)

(227,228,229)230,231,232,233,234,236,237,238(239,240,241)

Comment: Because twin primes (except 3 and 5) will always be of the form $6k-1$ and $6k+1$, for some integer $k$.

Comment: @vadim123 you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Every prime greater than 3 is of the form $6n\pm1$. Why? Hint: every number can be written as one of $6n, 6n+1, 6n+2, 6n+3, 6n+4, 6n+5$. Which of those have factors?

Bonus fun: What's special about $6$? Hint: look at the factors of the non-primes among $6n, 6n+1, 6n+2, 6n+3, 6n+4, 6n+5$. What if we try a different number that's the product of two small primes? Three small primes?